# Select every 3 elements with jQuery and add animation delay to them starting from iteration count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add animation delay starting from 0 to 3 elements like the example below:

```
<div style="animation-delay: 0s;"></div>
<div style="animation-delay: .25s;"></div>
<div style="animation-delay: .5s;"></div>
<div style="animation-delay: 0s;"></div>
<div style="animation-delay: .25s;"></div>
<div style="animation-delay: .5s;"></div>
<div style="animation-delay: 0s;"></div>
<div style="animation-delay: .25s;"></div>
<div style="animation-delay: .5s;"></div>
```

What am I doing right now:

```
var eventCards = $('.upcoming-events').find('.event-card');
eventCards.each(function(i, el){
    if( i % 3 == 0 ) {
        $(this).css({
            '-webkit-animation-delay': '.25' * i + 's',
            '-moz-animation-delay': '.25' * i + 's',
            '-o-animation-delay': '.25' * i + 's',
            'animation-delay': '.25' * i + 's'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `if` you add delay only on each third element.
If you want the exact result as your first example change code to:

```
eventCards.each(function(i, el){
    var j = i % 3;
        $(this).css({
            '-webkit-animation-delay': '.25' * j + 's',
            '-moz-animation-delay': '.25' * j + 's',
            '-o-animation-delay': '.25' * j + 's',
            'animation-delay': '.25' * j + 's'
        });
});
```

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/catthr/pen/KXKPwm)